# installing elementary OS primarily onto a USB while I trial Linux

Tags: usb

I do not want to write over my Windows OS. Is this possible?

I an amateur so ELI5 please... I know what Rufus is, if that helps.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Are you trying to follow these instructions on how to create a live USB drive?: https://elementary.io/docs/installation#creating-an-installation-medium

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if you just want to try it, just follow Paul's instructions or just use Etcher to make your USB bootable. Then boot from USB and try it. Simple as that. Nothing is changed in your system and you can try it freely without the need to install anything.

If you want to install in a USB drive (not recommended!), you need to select the USB when partitioning. Format the disk as EXT4 and mount it as '\'. I do not suggest this method because Elementary Boot menu is hidden and you may have difficulty in booting up.

If you want to install it in your HDD, next to your Windows, first you need to create a partition for Elementary. One partition is enough. Don't forget to make it big enough to install Elementary OS (20 or 30GB should be enough). 
Then create a live USB. Follow Paul's instructions or just download Etcher (works pretty well) to create your bootable USB.

Then boot from your USB (search how to do it in your PC). Basically you need to select USB and not your harddrive to boot-up.
When installing Elementary, select your new partition and mount it as EXT4. Also flag the format in that partition. On the dropdown, select '\'.
DO NOT format your Windows or personal Docs partition.
That is all you need to pay attention to. The rest is fairly intuitive.

Again, keep in mind Elementary OS boot menu may appear hidden and you may find it difficult to boot Windows.

Shout if you need more help.
Good luck man!